# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Xamarin Forms System.IO.Files keeps looking in the internal device storage

Tags: c#, .net, file, xamarin.forms

I'm currently trying to port my WPF C# App to android and iOS using Xamarin Forms. I have a .txt file in the assets folder in the Xamarin Android project, and I'm trying to read its contents using:

```
 string path =Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),filename);
        List<string> FENs = new List<string>();
        string Puzzles;
        Puzzles = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

the filename is "puzzles.txt", which is the txt I want to read from the assets folder. However, I keep getting the FileNotFoundException with this report: 'Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.companyname.stockfish_wins/files/.local/share/puzzles.txt"'
the solution's name is Stockfish Wins.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: The example here is for a .json file, but will work for a .txt file too https://johnjallan.co.uk/xamarin-android-reading-from-a-local-json-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using Xamarin.Essentials instead of trying to read the file from the correct location yourself https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=windows%2Candroid

Once installed you can use the File Sytem Helper to access a file within Assets (Android) or Resources (iOS) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android

```
using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(templateFileName))
{
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
      var fileContents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Asset Manager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows#reading-assets

```
// Read the contents of our asset
string content;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("read_asset.txt")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}
```